# Oracle PL/SQL function

Tags: oracle

I have a function for confluence 52 columns

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_one_row(i_code IN integer) RETURN CLOB IS
  l_columns  VARCHAR2(2000);
  l_res      CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT listagg(column_name,' || ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name ASC) AS GRAFIK
  INTO  l_columns
  FROM  user_tab_columns
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'GRAFIK';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '||l_columns||' FROM grafik WHERE kod_sotr=:A' INTO l_res USING i_code;
  RETURN l_res;
END;
```

The table Grafik has kod of worker, year and weeks, where 
designated their holidays letter y or o 
On a exit function displays

2017109909уууууооооо

First, meaning in conclutions is very fused, and not comfortable browse their. How devided the meaning?

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your dynamic SQL to add a separator between the columns; for example:

```
SELECT listagg(column_name,' || '', '' || ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY column_name ASC) AS GRAFIK
```

will add a comma between the values of the columns